# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: moz-nullprincipal

Tags: python, xml, openlayers, postgis

I am having a problem posting map data to postgis via apache2 --> geoserver-->OpenLayers 12.04.

I am receiving data from geoserver just fine but unable to post new data back.

The post error is:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: moz-nullprincipal:
#!/usr/bin/env python
-^
```

What I get for a response is the text of the proxy.cgi script provided by OpenLayers.  I have edited this script to include all sources found in the xml formed by the request to make sure that I have included all urls.

I have Python, Python2 and Python2.7 available but using any of these produces the same result.  All includes appear to be loading correctly.

I have read numerous posts related to this issue but none have provided a solution.  I used to be able to bypass the same domain issue by creating an index.html outside the apache-tomcat directory that would define an iframe that would call my actual site.html residing in /geoserver/www.  This no longer appears to work hence my proxy problem. This project is on hold until this issue is solved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Larry

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it.  Rather than using the OpenLayers proxy I found this blog:

http://bikerjared.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/ubuntu-12-04-mod-proxy-install-and-configuration/

that provides a very good tutorial on using an Apache2 proxy that fixed my problem nicely.